# Как сделать, чтобы текст на кнопке не выделялся?

Tags: html, css

```
<a href=''>
  <input>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href='#'>
    <input type="button" value="click" />
</a>
```

Comment: блин я забыл тайп указать